# Reusing firebase constant in lit-element

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, lit-element

In a lit-element component, I'm learning how to write to a Firebase document.

I set up the database reference as a constructor constant (docRef)... because it looked like a good place. However, I am not able to call it from the method writeToDb(). In the code below, everything works but you can see I have repeated the refDoc (=refDoc2).

I have tried "this.refDoc" but I get an error: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined. How do you do something similar in this case?

Thanks for any help!

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element'
import { store } from '../redux/store'

import { firestore } from '../database/config'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

import { connect } from 'pwa-helpers'

class ReduxFirebase extends connect(store)(LitElement) {    
  constructor(){
    super()
    const docRef = firestore.doc("samples/sandwichData")
    docRef.set({
      hotDogStatus: "not a sandwich!"
    })

  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <button @click="${this.writeToDb}">Change Status</button>
    `
  }

  writeToDb() {
    const docRef2 = firestore.doc("samples/sandwichData")
    docRef2.set({
      hotDogStatus: "may be a sandwich"
    })
  }
}

customElements.define('redux-firebase', ReduxFirebase)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `docRef` within `constructor` so you can only access it within the `constructor`.

```
  constructor(){
    super()
    const docRef = firestore.doc("samples/sandwichData")
    docRef.set({
      hotDogStatus: "not a sandwich!"
    })

  }
```

If you want it to be available anywhere within the class, you have to define it as an instance property, as a getter, or set it on `this.

Example of using a property. This is dependent on new [JS standard](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields).

```
class ReduxFirebase extends connect(store)(LitElement) {   
  docRef = firestore.doc("samples/sandwichData")

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.docRef.set({
      hotDogStatus: "not a sandwich!"
    })

  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <button @click="${this.writeToDb}">Change Status</button>
    `
  }

  writeToDb() {
    this.docRef.set({
      hotDogStatus: "may be a sandwich"
    })
  }
}
```

Example using a getter.

```
class ReduxFirebase extends connect(store)(LitElement) {   
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.docRef.set({
      hotDogStatus: "not a sandwich!"
    })

  }

  get docRef() {
    return firestore.doc("samples/sandwichData")
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <button @click="${this.writeToDb}">Change Status</button>
    `
  }

  writeToDb() {
    this.docRef.set({
      hotDogStatus: "may be a sandwich"
    })
  }
}
```

Example of setting on `this`.

```
class ReduxFirebase extends connect(store)(LitElement) {   
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.docRef = firestore.doc("samples/sandwichData")
    this.docRef.set({
      hotDogStatus: "not a sandwich!"
    })

  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <button @click="${this.writeToDb}">Change Status</button>
    `
  }

  writeToDb() {
    this.docRef.set({
      hotDogStatus: "may be a sandwich"
    })
  }
}
```

Note that you'll want to make sure `firestore.doc("samples/sandwichData")` is not performing a bunch of work before it's needed and define it in an [appropriate stage of the component lifecycle](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle).

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to define docRef differently than with a "this." and then using "this." to reuse the variable. I need to practice more.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to declare your [property](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/try/properties), if you are gonna initialize it from the constructor.

> ```
>  static get properties() {    return { docRef: { type: Object } };  }
> ```

Comment: Thank you too. In this case, it does not seem to be mandatory to declare properties. I tried with and without and it worked. Maybe this is necessary when binding data from component to component or values inserted in the render().